# aspdotnetstorefront - How to reference images stored on different server

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I want to store product images for my application on a different server, but can't figure out what to modify and where in the application files so that the product image is fetched from the different server.

Answer (score 0):

Found it finally. It was as simple as putting the external site name before the ImageUrl function. aspdnsf:ImageUrl() function returns the image url, something like "/images/Product/large/nnn.jpg"

For referencing external site just have to use < img src="http://www.somesitename.com{aspdnsf:ImageUrl(ProductID, 'Product', 'large', false)}" />